# Can i come back to my windows 7 after removing hdd?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I am using windows 7 now.
I am going to install Ubuntu on my external hard drive.
If i install ubuntu on external hard drive, then after installing, if i remove external hdd, can i go back to my original windows 7? Will it cause error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu can be installed in external drives, unlike Windows that only allows it under certain circunstances (Windows to Go feature).

However...

Unless you intend to change the boot order in BIOS anytime you want to run Ubuntu, you'll have to install the Grub Bootloader in the MBR of the internal drive, replacing the Windows Bootloader. This will need the external drive connected even if you want to boot Windows (from Grub).

Pay special attention to where to install Grub, the external drive, so you can boot  either OS independently  from BIOS. This goes without saying that if you're asking such basic question you don't know enough yet to do a correct and safe dual-boot installation.

Comment: You only need to change the boot order once (trivial).  Then you can boot either from the external drive with no change to the Windows drive.  Unplugging the external drive returns it to Windows, only.  Why would you replace the Windows bootloader rather than changing the boot order?

Answer (score -1):

If your not changing anything except for the external HDD, then yes; however be careful as installing Ubuntu to the external drive will wipe **all** of the data on it.